# Fingerprint sensor code won't work correctly with LCD 16x2

Tags: arduino-uno, lcd, adafruit

I am doing a fingerprint sensor that works with a 16x2 LCD. The code works correctly for the fingerprint sensor, but when I enter LCD code, the LCD works but the fingerprint stops working.

I am using an Arduino Uno and an Adafruit fingerprint sensor. Both the fingerprint and LCD are wired correctly and work separately. I have enrolled and tested fingerprints and it worked perfectly until I added LCD code.

```
#include <Adafruit_Fingerprint.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 5, 4, 3, 2);

int getFingerprintIDez();
// pin #2 is IN from sensor (GREEN wire)
// pin #3 is OUT from arduino  (WHITE wire)
SoftwareSerial mySerial(2, 3);

Adafruit_Fingerprint finger = Adafruit_Fingerprint(&mySerial);

void setup() {
 // set up the LCD's number of columns and rows:
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  // Print a message to the LCD.
  lcd.print("hello, world!");
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("fingertest");
  // set the data rate for the sensor serial port
  finger.begin(57600);
  if (finger.verifyPassword()) {
    Serial.println("Found fingerprint sensor!");
  } else {
    Serial.println("Did not find fingerprint sensor :(");
    while (1);
  }
  Serial.println("Waiting for valid finger...");
}

void loop() {
  getFingerprintIDez();
}

uint8_t getFingerprintID() {
  uint8_t p = finger.getImage();
  switch (p) {
    case FINGERPRINT_OK:
      Serial.println("Image taken");
      break;
    case FINGERPRINT_NOFINGER:
      Serial.println("No finger detected");
      return p;
    case FINGERPRINT_PACKETRECIEVEERR:
      Serial.println("Communication error");
      return p;
    case FINGERPRINT_IMAGEFAIL:
      Serial.println("Imaging error");
      return p;
    default:
      Serial.println("Unknown error");
      return p;
  }

  // OK success!
  p = finger.image2Tz();
  switch (p) {
    case FINGERPRINT_OK:
      Serial.println("Image converted");
      break;
    case FINGERPRINT_IMAGEMESS:
      Serial.println("Image too messy");
      return p;
    case FINGERPRINT_PACKETRECIEVEERR:
      Serial.println("Communication error");
      return p;
    case FINGERPRINT_FEATUREFAIL:
      Serial.println("Could not find fingerprint features");
      return p;
    case FINGERPRINT_INVALIDIMAGE:
      Serial.println("Could not find fingerprint features");
      return p;
    default:
      Serial.println("Unknown error");
      return p;
  }

  // OK converted!
  p = finger.fingerFastSearch();
  if (p == FINGERPRINT_OK) {
    Serial.println("Found a print match!");
  } else if (p == FINGERPRINT_PACKETRECIEVEERR) {
    Serial.println("Communication error");
    return p;
  } else if (p == FINGERPRINT_NOTFOUND) {
    Serial.println("Did not find a match");
    return p;
  } else {
   Serial.println("Unknown error");
    return p;
  }

  // found a match!
  Serial.print("Found ID #");
  Serial.print(finger.fingerID); 
  Serial.print(" with confidence of ");
  Serial.println(finger.confidence); 
}

// returns -1 if failed, otherwise returns ID #
int getFingerprintIDez() {
  uint8_t p = finger.getImage();
  if (p != FINGERPRINT_OK)  return -1;
  p = finger.image2Tz();
  if (p != FINGERPRINT_OK)  return -1;
  p = finger.fingerFastSearch();
  if (p != FINGERPRINT_OK)  return -1;
  // found a match!
  Serial.print("Found ID #");
  Serial.println(finger.fingerID);
  Serial.print("This Finger print related to : ");
  switch(finger.fingerID){
   case 0:  
     Serial.println("Subhy Mesmar");
     break;
   case 1 :  
     Serial.println("Amjad Mesmar");
     break;
  }
  return finger.fingerID;
}
```

In this image the fingerprint sensor works without LCD code:

[image: Fingerprint sensor works without lcd code]

And in this one the LCD works after adding code but the fingerprint sensor stopped working:

[image: lcd works after adding code but fingerprint sensors stopped working]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have pins 2 and 3 used by both the LCD and the SoftwareSerial used for the fingerprint sensor.

Use different pins for one or the other.

Worth looking at [the Software Serial reference](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/SoftwareSerial) to understand more about how it works.

Comment: is it safe to use different pins for fingerprint sensor ? , Wont changing pins 2,3 damage the sensor ?Please advise .

Comment: Yes it should be safe.